# How do I add Gutenberg block editor on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to enable editing of page/post sections on the front end (in a plugin or theme). I would like to open the Gutenberg editor on the frontend page. There seems to be no official way of doing it.

I'm basically looking to initialize an instance of the Gutenberg block editor in the front end, while retaining functionality and appearance just as in the "edit page/post" admin pages. How would I go about doing that ?

- I've looked in the official WordPress documentation and found nothing.
- I've scoured previous questions and most of them deal with adding TinyMCE to the front end, which does not work like the Gutenberg block editor.
- Every online resource I found was written in pre-Gutenberg times and adds tinyMCE to the front end.
- I have tried several of the resources available online, and basically ended up with an instance of tinyMCE in the front end.
- The only plugin I found doing this is "Advanced Custom Fields", as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M25ngsCh2kw

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT:

Block Themes (developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes) comes close to what you are looking for

---

Advanced Custom Fields ist a awesome Plugin. But you can create also your own form and api to create a page or post

Looks like this

### Form

```
<?php
/*
** Template Name: Add Post From Frontend
*/
?>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h3>Add New Post</h3>
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="ispost" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="" />
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label">Sample Content</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="sample_content"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label">Choose Category</label>
            <select name="category" class="form-control">
                <?php
                $catList = get_categories();
                foreach($catList as $listval)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$listval->term_id.'">'.$listval->name.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label">Upload Post Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="sample_image" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT" name="submitpost" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

### Validation

```
<script>
function returnformValidations()
{
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var content = document.getElementById("content").value;
    var category = document.getElementById("category").value;

    if(title=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter post title!");
        return false;
    }
    if(content=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter post content!");
        return false;
    }
    if(category=="")
    {
        alert("Please choose post category!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

### Save

```
<?php
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
    if(isset($_POST['ispost']))
    {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $user_login = $current_user->user_login;
        $user_email = $current_user->user_email;
        $user_firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;
        $user_lastname = $current_user->user_lastname;
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;

        $post_title = $_POST['title'];
        $sample_image = $_FILES['sample_image']['name'];
        $post_content = $_POST['sample_content'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];

        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $post_title,
            'post_content' => $post_content,
            'post_status' => 'pending',
            'post_name' => 'pending',
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'post_category' => $category
        );

        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'meta_key', true);

        if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata'))
        {
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
        if ($_FILES)
        {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array)
            {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
                {
                    return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                }
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $pid );
            }
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0)
        {
            //and if you want to set that image as Post then use:
            update_post_meta($pid, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
        }

        $my_post1 = get_post($attach_id);
        $my_post2 = get_post($pid);
        $my_post = array_merge($my_post1, $my_post2);

    }
}
else
{
    echo "<h2 style='text-align:center;'>User must be login for add post!</h2>";
}
?>
```

Code from: https://www.phpkida.com/how-to-add-post-from-frontend-in-wordpress-without-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm basically looking to instantiate the Gutenberg block editor on the front end, whereas the answer you have provided is to create a 'create page/post' form without the Gutenberg editor, which is not what I need.  There are plenty of resources available on how to do this, but this does not really address the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Norman Unfortunately, I don't know of any frontend editor you're looking for, the only ones that come close are block themes. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).